# Multicolumn in table not centered

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I have some issues with the usage of `\multicolumn`. As can be seen on the screenshot below, the words 'Classical' and 'Squared' are correctly aligned in the centre of the column. The word 'Exponential' however is not centered properly.

[image]

The code is:

```
\begin{table}[]
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{12pt}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l c c c c c c}
\hline\hline
\\\\[-4.3\medskipamount]
 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Classic} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Squared} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Exponential} \\
\textit{a} & 70 & 30 & 70 & 30 & 70 & 30 \\ [0.5ex]
\hline
\\\\[-3.9\medskipamount]
S100 & 91 & 31 & 71 & 01 & 21 & 41 \\
S100 & 91 & 31 & 71 & 01 & 21 & 41 \\
S100 & 91 & 31 & 71 & 01 & 21 & 41 \\
[1ex] \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

I would prefer to keep using the tabular package in the solution. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason is that this word  is a bit too long. Of course, you can increase the value of `\tabcolsep`. Another solution  uses a `\makebox[0pt]`, which allows the word to overlap slightly into the inter-column space, symmetrically.

Other than that,I recommend using the rules from `booktabs`, which have a variable thickness, and add some vertical padding around the rules. This will save you from adjusting by hand through spacing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs} 

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[]
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{12pt}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l c c c c c c}
\toprule\midrule
 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Classic} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Squared} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\makebox[0pt]{Exponential}} \\
\textit{a} & 70 & 30 & 70 & 30 & 70 & 30 \\ [0.5ex]
\midrule
\\\\[-3.9\medskipamount]
S100 & 91 & 31 & 71 & 01 & 21 & 41 \\
S100 & 91 & 31 & 71 & 01 & 21 & 41 \\
S100 & 91 & 31 & 71 & 01 & 21 & 41 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The `\makebox[0pt]` solution is working perfectly and is exactly what I'm looking for! Thank you so much for this!

Comment: Just in case: if you already load `mathtools`, it defines a `\clap` command which does the same job and is shorter to type.

Answer (score 3):

I would use `S` column type from the `siunitx` package, determine `S` column width and add `\cmidrule` below multi column cells:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l *{6}{S[table-format=2,
                         table-column-width=2em]}
                }
    \toprule
            & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Classic} 
                            & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Squared} 
                                            & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Exponential} \\
    \cmidrule{2-3}\cmidrule(lr){4-5}\cmidrule{6-7}
\textit{a}  & 70    & 30    & 70    & 30    & 70    & 30 \\
    \midrule
S100        & 91    & 31    & 71    & 01    & 11    & 41 \\
S100        & 91    & 31    & 71    & 01    & 21    & 41 \\
S100        & 91    & 31    & 71    & 01    & 21    & 41 \\ 
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: siunitx is an excellent package, but a little "overkill" when you have simple columns without decimals.

Comment: @Sveinung,partly you are right, but it offer simple way to define column width with centered content :-)

Comment: What about `w{c}{2em}`?

Answer (score 2):

The problem with using `\makebox[0pt]{}` is that, as Bernard said, the long header will overlap the inter-column spacing which may seem quite ugly. To avoid this, the sum of the widths of the two numeric columns should at least be equal to the width of the long header. This can be exactly calculated and defined in a new column type `C` as follows.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, array}    
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{12pt}
\newlength\wexp
\settowidth{\wexp}{Exponential}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr.5\wexp-\tabcolsep}}

\centering
\begin{tabular}{l c c c c C C}
\toprule
           & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Classic} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Squared} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Exponential} \\
\textit{a} & 70 & 30 & 70 & 30 & 70 & 30 \\ \midrule
S100       & 91 & 31 & 71 & 01 & 11 & 41 \\
S100       & 91 & 31 & 71 & 01 & 21 & 41 \\
S100       & 91 & 31 & 71 & 01 & 21 & 41 \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: I type of tabulars, you have three groups each of two columns. Those three groups should preferably be of the same width.

Answer (score 2):

I would have used:

1. The new `w{<align>}{<wd>}` column to fix the width of all column
2. `\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.5em}` (gives `1em` space between columns)
3. Trimmed `cmidrule`
4. No side bearings (`@{}`)
5. One grade smaller fonts in the headings
6. `booktab`-rules and `addlinespace[<wd>]`

[image]

And the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, array, caption} 

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{A table with figures\label{tab:atable}}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.5em}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}w{l}{4em}*{6}{w{c}{2em}}@{}}
\toprule
 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\small Classic} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\small Squared} & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{\makebox[0pt]{\small Exponential}} \\\cmidrule(l{0.75em}r{0.75em}){2-3}\cmidrule(l{0.75em}r{0.75em}){4-5}\cmidrule(l{0.65em}){6-7}
\textit{a} & 70 & 30 & 70 & 30 & 70 & 30 \\ 
\midrule\addlinespace[1ex]
S100 & 91 & 31 & 71 & 01 & 21 & 41 \\
S100 & 91 & 31 & 71 & 01 & 21 & 41 \\
S100 & 91 & 31 & 71 & 01 & 21 & 41 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: (+1) What' s this new column specifier, w? I vaguely remember having seen  a bunch of new specifiers mentioned recently, but I can't remember where nor when. Is it a new package?

Comment: @Bernard See [array manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/tools/array.pdf) pages 2 and 3. You have `w` and `W`, with slightly different attributes.

Comment: Thank you. This one is not new, but I've never used these specifiers.  I've found the new series of specifiers (which I've not tested yet): they're defined in the new `arraycols` package.

Comment: @Bernard Thank you for the reference to the `arraycols`-package. I was not aware of this.

Comment: It's very recent (july!).